# ERROR 1911 (HY000) at line 113: Unknown option 'COMPRESSION'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I've been ripping my hair out over this one for the past view days!

Okay, so server background:

**Centos 7 x86_64**
**Running Laravel**
**Running MariaDB**
**LAMP and all the good stuff is configured properly**

I'm trying to reinstall a source from a previous project a friend worked on and handed over to me; it's just a for fun project;.

but regardless

I'm trying to import the .sql file he sent over,

Whenver I try to add the .sql to the DB it spits out this error:

> ERROR 1911 (HY000) at line 113: Unknown option 'COMPRESSION'

Please help, I've been googling for days and I cannot find a single thing related to this that can benefit in fixing the problem,

I've tried restarting server multiple times, deleting DB's, making new ones, reinstalling laravel, mariadb, reinstalling centos, wiping servers, ect...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include line 113 so that we can see the context.

Comment: I found this, which could be relevant: https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-5097

Comment: Line 113: ) ENGINE=TokuDB AUTO_INCREMENT=312871140 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 `COMPRESSION`=TOKUDB_ZLIB;

Comment: It does appear to be https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-5097 then. Which version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: Also, do you have TokuDB support installed and enabled? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/enabling-tokudb/

Comment: TokuDB is not something for a Database Novice to cut his teeth on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your table engine to 'InnoDB' and default collation to 'latin1_swedish_ci'.

Comment: any idea how to do that? I have 0 SQL knowledge, this is why im stuck :/

Comment: Wait, idk why i choked up, Latin1_Sweish_ci is default

Comment: @RayCrush, please try this: Replace COMPRESSION=TOKUDB_ZLIB with ROW_FORMAT=TOKUDB_LZMA

Comment: zero sql knowledge but you jumping to TokuDB